# Adding eventhandler to treeitems in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

```
package helloworld;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    /*private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder_16.png"))
    );*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");        

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Jobs");
        TreeItem<String> rootItem2 = new TreeItem<String> ("Test");
        TreeItem<String> rootItem3 = new TreeItem<String> ("Datalens Help");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("Message" + i);            
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);

        }    


        List<TreeItem<String>> items=new ArrayList<>();



        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);  



      //  TreeView<String> tree2 = new TreeView<String> (rootItem2);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        //+-root.getChildren().add(tree2);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
        rootItem.addEventHandler(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED
                , new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("yolo");
            mouseEvent.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to trigger events by clicking on the individual treeitems, although the above code is not working. The event is triggered if I am adding the handler to the entire tree view. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As per the [`TreeItem` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html): "It is important to note however that a TreeItem is not a Node, which means that only the event types defined in TreeItem will be delivered. To listen to general events (for example mouse interactions), it is necessary to add the necessary listeners to the cells contained within the TreeView (by providing a cell factory)."

Comment: Can you give me an idea as to how do we do that?

Comment: Moreover I want different nodes to trigger different responses.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question